# AWS bucket policy statements priority order

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, aws-access-policy

I'm trying to restrict users access to my bucket using my bucket policy. I have a set of users, all of them have an S3FullAccess policy. I can't change anything in the IAM. I have only access to my bucket policy. So I want to control the user's access using the bucket policy. I'm splitting the users into 3 categories.

1. Admin access to my bucket (All access to my bucket)
2. User with limited access to my bucket (like get-bucket-policy, get-bucket-location)
3. No access to my bucket. (No access to my bucket)

The below policy is the one I tried, but it is not working.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "PolicyTesting",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<<account_id>>:user/users_with_limited_access"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetBucketPolicy",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::<<my_bucket_name>>",
                "arn:aws:s3:::<<my_bucket_name>>/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "1",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "NotPrincipal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<<account_id>>:user/admin_users"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::<<my_bucket_name>>",
                "arn:aws:s3:::<<my_bucket_name>>/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried the above policy, but only the admin users alone can access the bucket. The users with limited access unable to perform their granted actions like get-bucket-policy, get-bucket-location.They are getting an Access Denied exception. Help me to resolve this.

Comment: Group can't be principal, so how come you have it?

Comment: Actually, it's the user. for the explanation, I replace the user with a group. But I don't know that group can't be principals, I'll change it, but if you get my question please help me to find the solution

Answer (score 2):

There is no priority order in AWS IAM policies. Please refer to the policy evaluation logic [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_evaluation-logic.html).

The AWS enforcement code evaluates all policies within the account that apply to the request. If the code finds even one explicit deny that applies, the code returns a final decision of Deny.

Your current policy Deny all users except admin-users any S3 actions. Hence users_with_limited_access is unable to perform granted actions.

Please update your policy with the appropriate Principal(as per comments in your question) and refer to the updated policy below to make it work.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:user/s3-limited-access-user"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetBucketPolicy",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::example-bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::example-bucket/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "2",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:user/s3-no-access-user"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::example-bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::example-bucket/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "3",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:user/admin-user"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::example-bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::example-bucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: s3-limited-access-user has full s3 access in IAM, here we allowed them to use 3 permission, whether it will revoke all other permission like "list bucket", etc, to this bucket or they have all other permissions also?

Comment: The resulting permissions are the total permissions of both identity and resource policies. They will have all other permissions.

Answer (score 1):

You should be very careful with `NotPrincipal`. It is the best practice to avoid using it all together. Most of the time it is very easy to achieve the same functionality (policy semantics) without using the "dangerous" `NotPrincipal`.

I think you are better off creating specific IAM roles and assign them to the corresponding user groups you want to allow accessing the S3 bucket. After that block all other access to the bucket with an explicit `Deny` for `"Principal" : "*"` and `aws:userId` or `aws:PrincipalArn`.

Have a look at this article for more details https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-i-locked-the-whole-company-out-of-an-amazon-s3-bucket-1781de51e4be

Best, Stefan